# Exception using C# to ChangeLink IN Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

As part of a file storage migration project, I am trying to change some excel links in some excel workbooks to reflect the new file storage location.

I am using Winforms and C# in VS2017 RC to develop the solution that I intend to deploy.

In my solution; I am calling the ChangeLink method on the Excel Workbook object and passing in the old link, the new link and the Excel Link Type.

```
        public string ProcessFile(string fileName)
    {
        // Private member variable and placeholder declarations
        missingValue = Type.Missing;

        string oldLink;
        string newLink;
        int splitLocation;
        string stringToFind = "\\Finance";


        //Open the specified Excel Workbook
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook;

        StringBuilder resultsOut = new StringBuilder();

        if (MsOfficeHelper.IsPasswordProtected(fileName))
        {
            resultsOut = resultsOut.AppendLine("Password Protected - " + fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            // Open
            excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename: fileName, UpdateLinks: false);

            Array olinks = excelWorkbook.LinkSources(Excel.XlLink.xlExcelLinks) as Array;
            if (olinks != null)
            {
                if (olinks.Length > 0)
                {
                    resultsOut = resultsOut.AppendLine("Contains Links - " + fileName);
                    foreach (var olink in olinks)
                    {
                        oldLink = olink.ToString();
                        splitLocation = oldLink.IndexOf(stringToFind, 0);

                        newLink = "C:\\SteveTest\\" + oldLink.Substring(splitLocation + 1);

                        resultsOut = resultsOut.AppendLine(oldLink);
                        resultsOut = resultsOut.AppendLine(newLink);

                        try
                        {
                            excelWorkbook.ChangeLink(Name: oldLink, NewName: newLink, Type: Excel.XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks);
                        }
                        catch (Exception whoopsy)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(whoopsy.Message);
                            //throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            excelWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges: false);

        }
        return resultsOut.ToString();


    }
```

However, when I execute the ChangeLink method I get the following exception
[image: Exception Message]

Does anyone have any idea what is causing the exception?
Your considered responses will be greatly welcome.

Comment: its supposed to mean name not found - so, maybe you need to check somethings not gone wrong?

Comment: Does the newlink point to an actual file? Is it correctly formed?

Comment: @Madenis, yes the newLink does point to an actual file.   It should exist.

Comment: @BugFinder - a valid point that I will double check..

Comment: @BugFinder I did double check and something has indeed gone awry.

Comment: @BugFinder I did double check and something has indeed gone awry.  In my project; I have added a reference to the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.   The Excel Workbook where I am getting the Exception was created by a much earlier version of Excel and is saved as Excel 97-2003 type.   If I run my application against  woorkbooks created and saved in Excel 2010 or later, it works fine